# MySQL - Most efficient way to get the newest values of a joined table

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit, derived

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT 
  nodos.nombre,
  (SELECT super FROM atributo_16 WHERE nodoid=nodos.nodoid ORDER BY fecha DESC,created_at LIMIT 1) AS descuento_navision_super_cif,
  (SELECT regular FROM atributo_16 WHERE nodoid=nodos.nodoid ORDER BY fecha DESC,created_at LIMIT 1) AS descuento_navision_regular_cif,
  (SELECT diesel FROM atributo_16 WHERE nodoid=nodos.nodoid ORDER BY fecha DESC,created_at LIMIT 1) AS descuento_navision_diesel_cif
FROM 
  nodos 
WHERE 
  nodos.nodotipoid=8;
```

This works fine, but it is slow.  The query is repeated (3x) on this example to the same table and with the same WHERE.  The real query has 20 of these kinds of subqueries to different tables.  I want to optimize the query.

---

This is one of my tries to speed it up, using derived tables.  Making a [fecha, created_at] index, which gave it a speed boost, but the query is not working, since the LIMIT 1 part of the query is applied before the JOIN, and I don't seem to be able to add the nodoid part to the WHERE statement, which would fix the issue.

```
SELECT 
  nodos.nombre,
  descuentos.super AS descuento_navision_super_cif,
  descuentos.regular AS descuento_navision_regular_cif,
  descuentos.diesel AS descuento_navision_diesel_cif
FROM 
  nodos 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT nodoid, super, regular, diesel, ulsd 
    FROM atributo_16 ORDER BY fecha DESC,
    created_at LIMIT 1)descuentos ON descuentos.nodoid=nodos.nodoid
WHERE 
 nodos.nodotipoid=8
```

**UPDATED**
This is the EXPLAIN table for the first query.

```
id  select_type         table        type  possible_keys  key         key_len  ref                             rows  Extra                        
1   PRIMARY             nodos        ref   nodotipoid     nodotipoid  4        const                           226                                
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  atributo_16  ref   nodoid         nodoid      4        nodos.nodoid                    376   Using where; Using filesort  
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  atributo_16  ref   nodoid         nodoid      4        nodos.nodoid                    376   Using where; Using filesort  
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  atributo_16  ref   nodoid         nodoid      4        nodos.nodoid                    376   Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: can you post an `EXPLAIN SELECT` and some stats about the table like the indexes and amount of rows in each.

Comment: The amount of rows are ~400 for nodos and ~10000 for atributo_16

Comment: Not sure if i miss something - but why do you use a subselect in the second query. As far as i see, you'll be fine just joining the two tables on nodeid and then use ORDER BY and LIMIT 1.

Comment: A simple join would return 1000 rows per each nodeid.  I just need the newest register on that table.

Comment: Can we see the explain for Giorgios's query

Answer (score 0):

Try using variables in a derived table to get the greatest-per-group record:

```
SELECT 
  nodos.nombre,
  super AS descuento_navision_super_cif,
  regular AS descuento_navision_regular_cif,
  diesel AS descuento_navision_diesel_cif
FROM 
  nodos AS t1 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT super, regular, diesel, nodoid, 
          @rn := IF (@id = nodoid, @rn + 1,
                    IF (@id := nodoid, 1, 1)) AS rn
   FROM atributo_16
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0,  @id := -1) AS vars
   ORDER BY nodoid, fecha DESC,created_at
) AS t2 ON t1.nodoid = t2.nodoid AND t2.rn = 1
WHERE 
  nodos.nodotipoid=8;
```

I've made the assumption that `nodoid<>-1`, so it's safe to initialize `@id` using this value.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works, but the result is actually slower than my original query.  Do you think I need some keys created on the table?

Comment: @JoeGalind Try creating an index on `(nodoid, fecha)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *atributo_16.atributo16id* is primary key - You can put the dependent subselect into the where clause:

```sql
SELECT n.nombre, a.super, a.regular, a.diesel
FROM nodos n
LEFT JOIN atributo_16 a USING(nodoid)
WHERE n.nodotipoid = 8
  AND (
    a.atributo16id = (
      SELECT a1.atributo16id
      FROM atributo_16 a1
      WHERE a1.nodoid = n.nodoid
      ORDER BY a1.fecha DESC, a1.created_at
      LIMIT 1
    ) 
    OR a.nodoid IS NULL -- skip this line if using inner join
  )
```

An index on (nodoid, fecha, created_at) can improve the performance.

A more complex solution is to search for max(fecha) then search the result for min(created_at) and then join the result with the physical tables on the min/max values:

```sql
SELECT n.nombre, a.super, a.regular, a.diesel
FROM nodos n
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT minc.nodoid, MIN(a.atributo16id) minpk
    FROM (
        SELECT maxf.nodoid, maxf.maxfecha, MIN(a.created_at) mincreated
        FROM (
            SELECT a.nodoid, MAX(a.fecha) maxfecha
            FROM atributo_16 a
            JOIN nodos n USING(nodoid)
            WHERE n.nodotipoid = 8
            GROUP BY a.nodoid
        ) maxf
        JOIN atributo_16 a
            ON  a.nodoid = maxf.nodoid
            AND a.fecha  = maxf.maxfecha
        GROUP BY maxf.nodoid, maxf.maxfecha
    ) minc
    JOIN atributo_16 a
        ON  a.nodoid     = minc.nodoid
        AND a.fecha      = minc.maxfecha
        AND a.created_at = minc.mincreated
    GROUP BY minc.nodoid, minc.maxfecha, minc.mincreated
) lastreg USING(nodoid)
LEFT JOIN atributo_16 a ON a.atributo16id = lastreg.minpk 
WHERE n.nodotipoid = 8
```

This one will be slow without an aproriate index. But its quite fast with an index on (nodoid, fecha) and probably a bit faster with an index on (nodoid, fecha, created_at).

**Update:** Here is an other short solution, wich might be more intuitive for you, because the subselect is based on your original query.

```sql
SELECT
  n.nombre,
  a.super AS descuento_navision_super_cif,
  a.regular AS descuento_navision_regular_cif,
  a.diesel AS descuento_navision_diesel_cif
FROM (
  SELECT nodos.nombre,
    (SELECT atributo16id FROM atributo_16 WHERE nodoid=nodos.nodoid ORDER BY fecha DESC,created_at LIMIT 1) AS atributo16id
  FROM nodos
  WHERE nodos.nodotipoid=8
) n
LEFT JOIN atributo_16 a ON a.atributo16id = n.atributo16id
```